# Wordpress Customizer sanitize_callback: How to Reset to Default on Fail

Tags: theme-customizer

I check the sanity of some settings with `sanitize_callback`. It works, but on fail, I want to reset the value do the default one. How can I do that?

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    $attribute[0],
    array(
        "default" => $attribute[1],
        "sanitize_callback" => $validate_func,
    )
);
```

**EDIT**

An example for `$validate_func` is `kb_validate_url_facebook` which checks if the setting is an URL and if it contains *facebook.com*.

```
function kb_validate_url( $url, $valid, $default ) {
    if ( $url === "" ) return $default;

    $url = strtolower( esc_url_raw( $url ) );
    if ( !strpos( $url, $valid ) ) {
        if ( $url !== "" ) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return $url;
}

function kb_validate_url_facebook( $url ) {
    return kb_validate_url( $url, 'facebook.com', 'www.facebook.com/USERNAME' );
}
```

Comment: Please expand on your code sample to include what `$validate_func` is and what `$attribute` contains.

Comment: It does (and should) not really matter what exactly the values are since this is a general question. ;)

Comment: It would be easier to provide an answer if you had a full working example.

Comment: It seems like the use case you have in mind is to allow for a value to be cleared from a customizer control to have its default value printed? In other words, so that `get_theme_mod( 'facebook_url', KB_FACEBOOK_URL_DEFAULT )` will still ultimately return the `default` value since since after a theme mod is once saved the second argument to `get_theme_mod()` is then is bypassed in favor of the value stored in the DB, even if it is empty. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

In the `sanitize_callback` function you can look at the second argument which is the `WP_Customize_Setting` instance and access the `default` property there when returning due to an empty provided value:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', function( WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'facebook_url', array(
        'default' => 'https://www.facebook.com/USERNAME',
        'sanitize_callback' => function( $url, $setting ) {
            if ( empty( $url ) ) {
                return $setting->default; // <===== Accessing default value.
            }

            $url = strtolower( esc_url_raw( $url ) );
            $host = wp_parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST );
            if ( ! preg_match( '/^(www\.)?facebook\.com$/', $host ) ) {
                return new WP_Error( 'invalid_url', __( 'Invalid URL or not one for Facebook', 'kb' ) );
            }
            return $url;
        },
    ) );
} );
```